# Folding electrical tape around the bar tape as it reaches the middle of the handlebars

Tags: handlebar-tape

So....

I saw a bike parked up at work with drop bars and bar tape that looked interesting.

As the bar tape reached the middle of the handlebars rather than wrapping electrical tape around the end to hold it down it looked like the electrical tape had been wrapped around the bar tape inside out.  It's difficult to explain but it meant that when the bar tape ended the electrical tape also ended.

Anyway i'm hoping this will make sense to someone as it would like to do the same on my bike :)

Comment: I suppose you haven't taken a picture that would save you 1000 words... I believe the reason for putting electrical tape reversed is to prevent bar wrap unwinding should it get damaged. It is explained in this video from Park Tool on "How to Wrap Handlebars for Road Bikes" https://youtu.be/5MzIiv7pewE?t=725 Personally, I'm using dual-sided adhesive tape for that (I will post a video on that some day).

Comment: Do you mean there was no electrical tape visible? If so it could be that the tape was wrapped starting at the tops, instead of starting at the bar ends, meaning no need for tape securing any loose bar tape. This is done for aesthetics sometimes.

Comment: Mike's right - grab a photo next time.  I have a bunch of random bike photos on my phone, some nice and some nightmares.

Comment: Bartape is reasonably forgiving stuff - try it for yourself and report back in an answer.   I think the trick will be figuring out how to stop the tail-end from coming loose and flapping about.

Comment: Also, keep your eye out at work in case the bike returns?